# PHP: small issue with str_replace

Tags: php

I need to do array_key_exists with a modified string, however, I am getting a slight issue before.

The following illustrates it:

```
$loggers = array('StackOverflow' => 'Stack Overflow');
$logger_name = str_replace(' ', '', $header['fromaddress']); //Remove space
echo $logger_name;
echo $loggers[$logger_name];
echo $loggers['StackOverflow'] . '<br/>';
```

The following is the output:

```
StackOverflow  //echo $logger_name
Notice: Undefined index: StackOverflow in C:\... on line x //looks like not found using $logger_name
Stack Overflow //I can find it directly
```

More edits:

Looks like the problem is that the first output, even though it says 'StackOverflow' it has a length of 35 when using the function strlen($logger_name)... I am not sure why, and if there is any way to convert this to a correct string?

Comment: You removed the spaces, of course they will be not identic.

Comment: I'm not sure whats your problem ... ? 

The first line causes $test to change to 'Thisisatest' so obviously its not equal to 'This is a test' ... ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I am glad I cheered up your day though :p

Comment: What does `var_dump($logger_name);` say? It *should* be `string(13) "StackOverflow"`.

Comment: It actually says string(35) "StackOverflow" :s

Answer (score 2):

I Assume your $header['fromaddress'] has value other then "**Stack Overflow**" Lets say it is "stack overflow"

> str_replace(' ', '', $header['fromaddress']);

will convert this to "stackoverflow".

and this won't give you output as array key in PHP is case sensitive.

```
echo $loggers[$logger_name];  //  $loggers['stackoverflow']
echo $loggers['StackOverflow'];
```

and here is the updated code and output...

```
$loggers = array('StackOverflow' => 'Stack Overflow');
$logger_name = str_replace(' ', '', 'Stack Overflow'); //Remove space
echo $logger_name. '<br/>';
echo $loggers[$logger_name]. '<br/>';
echo $loggers['StackOverflow'] . '<br/>';
```

**OUTPUT :-**

```
StackOverflow
Stack Overflow
Stack Overflow
```

Comment: and what about header array ?

Comment: Updated my answer can you please try it now?

Comment: No... you can see where I show the output that echo $logger_name is StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$text = "This is a test";
$array = explode(' ', $text);
$exists = array_key_exists($key, $array);
echo $exists;
```

Hope it helps